# Linear MMSE estimate of MMSE estimator

Tags: probability, probability-theory, mean-square-error

This question is prompted by a recent discussion ([Conditional Expectation a Decreasing Function Implies Covariance is nonpositive](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87662)) about the relationship between conditional expectation and covariance.

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are zero-mean unit-variance random variables with covariance (and correlation coefficient) $\rho$.  The
minimum-mean-square error (MMSE) estimator of $Y$ given $X$ is 
the random variable $g(X)$ that minimizes $E[(Y-g(X))^2]$, and as is
well known, $$g(X) = E[Y \mid X] ~\text{minimizes}~E[(Y-g(X))^2]$$
It is also well known that 
$E[g(X)] = E[E[Y\mid X]] = E[Y] = 0$.  In general, 
$g(X)$ is a nonlinear function.
On the other hand, if the estimator is restricted to being 
of the form $\hat{Y} = aX + b$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, 
then the *linear* MMSE estimator of $Y$ given $X$ is 
$\hat{Y} = \rho X$, that is,
$$a = \rho, ~ b = 0, ~\text{minimizes}~E[(Y-aX-b)^2].$$
The linear MMSE estimator $\rho X$ has a mean-square-error 
$E[(Y-\rho X)^2] = 1 - \rho^2$ and so the mean-square-error 
of the MMSE estimator $g(X)$ can be no larger:
$$E[(Y-g(X))^2] \leq 1 - \rho^2.$$

A simplified version of the question in the 
[previous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87662) is: 
if $g(\cdot)$ is a decreasing
function of its argument, show that $\rho$ is nonpositive.

My question is: what is the *linear* MMSE estimate of $g(X) = E[Y \mid X]$ 
given $X$?  That is, what choice of real numbers $c$ and $d$ minimizes
$E[(g(X) - cX - d)^2]$?  Since $g(X)$ and $X$ both have zero mean and
$X$ has unit variance, standard linear MMSE estimator theory gives that
$d = 0$ and 
$$c = \frac{\text{cov}(g(X),X)}{\text{var}(X)} = \text{cov}(g(X),X) = E[Xg(X)]$$
which I think might work out to be $\rho$, but I am not sure about this.
Any suggestions on how to proceed further would be appreciated.

Comment: Your final result is correct: for simple least-squares regression of $Y$ on $X$, the line passes through the point $(\mu_X,\mu_Y)$ with gradient $\rho \dfrac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X} = \dfrac{\text{cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_X^2}$.  So here it is just $\rho$.

Comment: I am somewhat uncomfortable with your language, since I fear that this way of using the word "linear" might feed into the popular misunderstanding that the reason why linear regression in called linear regression is that one is fitting a line.  People who think that then find it confusing when a statistician insists that one is doing linear regression when one fits a parabola or a sine wave, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I thought about editing the question to say something like "straight-line MMSE estimation" instead of "linear MMSE estimation" but decided against it because linear MMSE estimation is reasonably well-established, at least in the engineering literature: Google provides over $900,000$ hits. But, thanks for your answer which I am accepting. I was able to show $E[Xg(X)] = \rho$ for discrete and for jointly continuous random variables but wanted a proof that did not rely on special cases, and your answer gave me exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct.  By the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) we have
$$
\begin{align}
E(X(Y-g(X)) & = E(\;E(X(Y-g(X))\mid X)\;) \\  \\
& = E(\; E(XY\mid X) - E(Xg(X)\mid X)\;) \\  \\
& = E(\; XE(Y\mid X) - Xg(X) \;) \\  \\
& = E( Xg(X) - Xg(X)) = 0.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore
$$
E(XY) = E(Xg(X)).
$$